# Slow SSRS Query against SSAS Cube (SQL Server 2008R2)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have SSAS and SSRS 2008R2. The end goal is to get the report with Daily MarketValue for each Portfolio and Security Combination. MarketValue has SCOPE calculation to Select Last Existing for Date Dimension. If the SCOPE is removed the query still takes 6 min t complete. and with SCOPE statement it timeout after 1 hour. here is my query

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{[Measures].[MarketValue]} ON COLUMNS
,NON EMPTY 
{
[Portfolio].[PortfolioName].[PortfolioName].ALLMEMBERS*
[Effective Date].[Effective Date].[Effective Date].ALLMEMBERS*
[Security].[Symbol].[Symbol].ALLMEMBERS
}
DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
MEMBER_CAPTION
,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
ON ROWS
FROM EzeDM
WHERE 
(
[AsOn Date].[AsOn Date].&[2014-06-17T06:32:41.97]
,[GoldenCopy].[Frequency].&[Daily]
,[GoldenCopy].[GoldenCopyType].&[CitcoPLExposure]
,[GoldenCopy].[PointInTime].&[EOP]
,[GoldenCopy].[PositionType].&[Trade-Date]
);
```

The `SCOPE` statement I have for MarketValue Measure is

```
SCOPE 
[Effective Date].[Effective Date].MEMBERS;
THIS = 
Tail
(
(EXISTING 
[Effective Date].[Effective Date].MEMBERS)
,1
).Item(0);
END SCOPE;
```

Security DIM has around 4K values. Portfolio DIM has around 100 Values and `EffectiveDate` DIM has around 400 values.

If I remove the `EffectiveDate` from the cross join the query is taking less than 2 seconds.

So far I have tried different combinations and found that the slowness is due to the cross join between DIM with large values in them. but then I am thinking is 4000 values in DIM is actually large? people must have done the same reporting efficiently right?

Is this a `SCOPE` calculation? If so why does it get slower only when `EffectiveDate` is in the cross join?

Appreciate any help.

**EDIT:1**
Adding some more details about the current environment if that helps :
We do not have Enterprise version and currently we do not have any plans to ask our clients to upgrade to Enterprise version.

Security Dimension has around 40 attribute but 2 of them will always have data and at most "up to 6" may have any data. not sure if Attribute being not used in `MDX` query still affects the query performance "regardless it has data or not" 
After reading the "Chris Webb" blog on MDX query improvements I notice the property is true for ALL Attributes in ALL Dimension.

```
"AttributeHierarchyEnabled = True"
```

For testing I have marked FALSE to all except currently I am using.

I do not have any aggregations defined on cube and I have started with building Aggregations using "Design Aggregations" wizard. after that I profile the same reporting query and didn't see any tick for "get data from Aggregations" event.

So currently I am working on preparing/testing "Usage Based Aggregation"

**EDIT:2**

So I created the log table with 50% logging sampling and ran 15-20 different reporting queries Client is expecting to run and saw some data in log table. I used the Wizard for Usage Based Aggregation and let SSAS finds out Estimated Row Count. 
it was strange that it did not generate any aggregations.

I also tried the approach of changing the Aggregation property to LastChild As Frank suggested and it worked great but then I realize I can not pick LastChild Value for MarketValue for all Dimension. it is Additive across Security Dimension but not across Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that getting rid of the whole `SCOPE` statement and instead setting the AggregateFunction property of the measures to `LastChild` or `LastNonEmpty` would speed up the calculation. This would require `[Effective Date]` to be the first dimension tagged as time, and you need SQL Server Enterprise edition for these AggregateFunctions to be available.

Comment: good to know that enterprise edition has out of the box this functionality "LastNonEmpty". As of now we are not planning to make enterprise version mandatory for our clients. I have update my question with some more details just in case if it helps all to direct me in specific direction.

Comment: @AnupShah I just came across the fact that standard edition supports "LastChild" (see the footnote for line "Semi-additive Measures" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx#BISemModel_multi).

Comment: humm, I will check this out today.

Comment: I did test "LastChild" Aggregate-Function property and I was surprised how much performance difference it has. the query with SCOPE statement that was not even finishing after 3 hours and after chnaging this property it is taking 1.02 minutes on cold cache. Only thing is I will not be able to chnage this property because I need to SUM the MarketValue Accross securities but pick the Last only if viewed accross time. So it is not additive across time but additive across Security-Symbol.

Comment: @AnupShah That is exactly what "LastChild" does: It sums across all dimensions except the time dimension. For this specific dimension, it applies the "LastChild" logic.

Comment: i got it now. I setup the clean env locally and started from fresh. It was some issue with my previous data and/or environment setup. for some reason when I choose specific filter for Attribute "GoldenCopy" in my query I do not see the mentioned behavior, i.e. I do not see the MarketValue showing up at portfolio or security level. I have to have bring Effective Date on rows to see the values. But when I change my specific filter value for "GoldenCopy" attribute it worked. I will still have to investigate this behavior yet it is different issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: is possible to configure a measure's Aggregation property as MAX across Security, but LastChild across Time? I have another measure AUM which I need to pick Max across Security but Last Across Time.

Comment: @AnupShah No, this is too complex to be just configurable. You would have to use the calculation script for that.